# Distribute an xml file with my Android app

Tags: android, xml

I have created a java application using "**Simple**" that allows me to serialize objects in some configuration xml file.
These files must be redistributed with my android application, but here comes the problem:

1. Where do I place the files? Is it better to place them in the res/xml folder or create a custom path to the assets folder (assets/myfiles)?
2. In the examples given with Simple if I want to deserialize an object I need an xml file:

   `File fl = new File ("string to file path");`

but if the file is in the resources of my project, how do I get the file?
Searching the internet I found only examples that use a XmlResourceParser but I don't know how to use it with Simple!

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to include files you can later access from your application you'll need to put them in the assets folder. After your application has been installed and running you can get get that xml file by using the AssetManager class:

AssetManager assets = getAssets();
InputStream stream = asset.open("filename");

That will give you an InputStream for you to do whatever you need.